# iOS -- is it possible to force a UILabel subclass object to become the first responder?

Tags: iphone, ios, first-responder

Is there any way to do this?

I tried putting the following into the subclass:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder 
{
    return YES;
}
```

But when I sent the object a becomeFirstResponder message, it still didn't become the first responder.

Comment: UILabel becoming a first responder? What do you want it to respond?

Comment: It inherits from UIResponder so it does have the capability.

Comment: I'm using someone's library that does stuff when an object with certain properties becomes the first responder.  It also sends messages to the first responder.  I happen to want to tie all this in to my label.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You should:

1. Override `becomeFirstResponder` to return `YES`.
2. Set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`.
3. Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to handle taps.
4. Call `becomeFirstResponder` from the tap handler.

You can even override `inputView` to get a input control at the bottom of the screen. Otherwise there will be nothing.

Comment: What I should return in `inputView` to see the keyboard on the screen?

Comment: @derpoliuk thanks for the comment. My fault, didn't check that UIKeyboard class is a private API.

Comment: So there is no way to get keyboard on the screen after `UILabel` becomes first responder? I'm trying to mimic Viber or Telegram behaviour, when the keyboard is on the screen and long press on the chat message shows `UIMenuController`.

Comment: Not sure that your UILabel should become first responder to be able to display a UIMenuController. Are you sure your UITextField responsible for the keyboard on screen is in the same UIViewController?

Comment: I call `[UILabel becomeFirstResponder]` because of `UIMenuController`. In this case `UILabel` able to respond for `copy:` message from `UIMenuController`. If I call `[UITextView becomeFirstResonder]` `UILabel` no longer able to respond to the `copy:`.
Thanx for response.

Answer (score 0):

I have no definite answer, just a few (maybe crazy) ideas: Have you also tried to override `becomeFirstResponder` to return `YES`? Does it have `userInteractionEnabled` also set to `YES`?

Otherwise, make it a custom UIButton instead of a custom UILabel...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Subclass UILabel and override these methods:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action
                  withSender:(id)sender
    {
        return (action == @selector(copy:));
    }

    - (void)copy:(id)sender {
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:self.text];
    }
```

Add Gesture to your label to detect tap.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LongPressDetected:)];
[_messageLabel addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Handle gesture event, present a UIMenuController with the desired frame:

```
- (void)LongPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {

        [_messageLabel becomeFirstResponder];
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setTargetRect:_messageLabel.bounds inView:_messageLabel];
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:YES animated:NO];
    }
```